# CSS - Absolute positioning jerky in Microsoft Edge

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, microsoft-edge

I am implementing a slip scrolling function to reveal / hide a fixed logo on scroll like this...

```js
var setLogo = function() {
 $('.moveable').each(function() {
    $(this).css('top',
      $('.default').offset().top -
      $(this).closest('.container').offset().top
    );
  });
};
 
$(document).scroll(function() {
  setLogo();
});
 
setLogo();
```

```css
img {
  width: 200px;
}

.container {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  min-height: 600px;
  padding: 1em;
}

.dark {
  background: #333;
}
 
.light {
  background: #fff;
}

.gradient {
  background: #15EA24;
}

.default {
  position: fixed;
}
 
.moveable {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container dark">
  <img src="https://www.marcoguglie.it/Codepen/SlipScrollEffect/img/skateboard-light.svg" class="default">
</div>
 
<div class="container light">
  <img src="https://www.marcoguglie.it/Codepen/SlipScrollEffect/img/skateboard-dark.svg" class="moveable">
</div>

<div class="container gradient">
  <img src="https://www.marcoguglie.it/Codepen/SlipScrollEffect/img/skateboard-gradient.svg" class="moveable">
</div>
```

Everything looks great in every browser I have tried apart from Microsoft Edge.

When scrolling, the logos jump around and generally look jerky.

Anyone any ideas why this is happening and if there is a workaround?

Answer (score 1):

One idea, is not to use Javascript, but do with pure CSS.

Below is an example.

The trick is, to position the images fixed, and then clip them.  The reason we need the clip container is that position fixed will ignore overflow, but doesn't ignore clip.

> update: just tested this snipped in Edge, will see what's causing it.

```css
img {
  width: 200px;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  height: 600px; 
}

.clipper {
  position: absolute;
  clip: rect(0, auto, auto, 0);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.dark {
  background: #333;
}
 
.light {
  background: #fff;
}

.gradient {
  background: #15EA24;
}


.moveable {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container dark">
  <div class="clipper">
    <img src="https://www.marcoguglie.it/Codepen/SlipScrollEffect/img/skateboard-light.svg" class="moveable image1">
  </div>
</div>

 
<div class="container light">
  <div class="clipper">
<img src="https://www.marcoguglie.it/Codepen/SlipScrollEffect/img/skateboard-dark.svg" class="moveable image2">
  </div>
</div>


<div class="container gradient">
 <div class="clipper">
  <img src="https://www.marcoguglie.it/Codepen/SlipScrollEffect/img/skateboard-gradient.svg" class="moveable image3">
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That is not working for me in Microsoft Edge, still get the jumpiness on the initial image and then no images after that

Comment: Yeah, just seeing now why.. , typical MS.. :(

Comment: Ok, this looks like a bug with Edge :(,  a soon as you apply the clip, the image disappears,.  @HaiPham looks like a good alternative.  I'll leave this post here, in case someone might be able to figure out why Edge fails.  Or reference for me in case I'll have another stab at it later..

Comment: @fightstarr20 how about combining both mine and Keith solution (in responsive mode for mobile)?

Comment: I have a feeling this is something to do with repainting and performance

Answer (score 1):

My solution without using Javascript, send image to background and set `background-attachment: fixed;` do the trick:

```css
img {
  width: 200px;
}

.container {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  min-height: 600px;
}

.dark {
  background: #333;
}
 
.light {
  background: #fff;
}

.gradient {
  background: #15EA24;
}
 
.img {
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}
.img1 {
    background-image: url('https://www.marcoguglie.it/Codepen/SlipScrollEffect/img/skateboard-light.svg');
}
.img2 {
    background-image: url('https://www.marcoguglie.it/Codepen/SlipScrollEffect/img/skateboard-dark.svg');
}
.img3 {
    background-image: url('https://www.marcoguglie.it/Codepen/SlipScrollEffect/img/skateboard-gradient.svg');
}
```

```html
<div class="container dark">
    <div src="" class="default img img1"></div>
</div>

<div class="container light">
    <div src="https://www.marcoguglie.it/Codepen/SlipScrollEffect/img/skateboard-dark.svg" class="moveable img img2"></div>
</div>

<div class="container gradient">
    <div src="https://www.marcoguglie.it/Codepen/SlipScrollEffect/img/skateboard-dark.svg" class="moveable img img3"></div>
</div>
```

Hope this help.

Comment: That solution will not work on mobile devices as background attachment fixed is poorly supported.

Answer (score -1):

I try to produce the issue on my side with MS Edge and Chrome.

I find that issue is only producible, If you directly run the code from Stack Overflow code snippet. But if you run the code in MS Edge or Chrome locally than it runs smooth.

Below is the testing result in Stack Overflow code snippet.

[image]

Output in MS Edge (Microsoft Edge 42.17134.1.0 / Microsoft EdgeHTML 17.17134):

[image]

Output in chrome:

[image]

So you can see that if you run the code in browser directly than it is working fine. I suggest you to make a test on your side and let us know about your testing result.

Comment: But none of your other examples work, the image is not fixed and does not reveal as it scrolls

Comment: I just try to run your code in MS Edge. It is the same code that you had posted above. You can also try to make a test with it and check on your side. I only try to test whether image display with jerking effect or not. based on my testing result, image is not jerking in MS Edge. If you have any other issues than you can try to provide a detailed information about that. We will try to make a test with it to check the issue. Thanks for your understanding.